# how do I process dynamically generated javascript code with PHP and send the result as an email?

Tags: php, javascript, html

**this is the javascript code**

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**this is the html code**

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts">
            <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

i'm trying to collect all the inputs generated and process them with php

Comment: You could use ajax for doing this

Comment: @karthikr, AJAX is not necessary.  Something server-side is.

Comment: Is it ok to go away from the page (reload it) on submit?

Comment: @Sergio yes you can navigate away from the page on submit but i wouldn't mind processing on the same page

Comment: @popnoodles the form enables users to add unlimited inputs i'm trying to get all of them (no matter the amt) and send them for processing.

Comment: @popnoodles yes i have. do try running the code. then you'll understand what i'm talking about. thanks

Comment: please help make appropriate corrections then. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** Add a `<form>` tag before #p_scents so all the new `<input type="text" ...` are inside the form. Close the tag after #p_scents with ` and add a submit button or javascript function. In the form action you can add the same name of the file you are in (assuming it can handle php), otherwise create a php file.

**2-** Then you need to create a foreach loop in the php file to search for all the inputs. Colect them with `$_POST`.

You can do this way:
When you add new fields you can just keep them identicall and serialize them. Use `name="p_scnt[]"` in all input fields. The one already in the html and identical for all the generated by javascript. This will serialize them.

In the php file use: 
`foreach($_POST["p_scnt"] as $value) { … }`, inside the `{` `}` you can writhe your php code.

**3-** About making email from the variables you will have it's recomended to use some email library to avoid header injection, but anyway here is an example:

```
$to      = 'recepient@somemail.com';
$subject = 'Subject here';
$message = "Content";
$message .= "more Content";
$message .= "even more Content or a variable".$variable;
$headers = 'From: sender@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: sender@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Sergio could you also help me with the for loop to search for all inputs?

Comment: Just updated my answer, let me know if you can do it from here.